# How do i Make a Custom UEFI bootable live CD?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, uefi, live-cd

I tried the following from: LinuxQuestions.org.

```
 mkisofs -U -J -joliet-long -r -v -T -o ttylinux.iso -b boot/isolinux/isolinux.bin -c boot/isolinux/boot.cat \
    -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e efiboot.img -no-emul-boot .
```

and

```
../grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi -d . -o BOOTX64.efi -p "/EFI/BOOT" part_gpt part_msdos fat ext2 normal chain boot \
```

But I can't find `efiboot.img` or `BOOTX64.efi` in my system(`find -name` or via `apt-cache search`). I am running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

> How can I Make a customized UEFI bootable live CD?

Source:

- [Make UEFI bootable live CD - LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/make-uefi-bootable-live-cd-926021/)
- [UEFIBooting - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting)
- [UEFI - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: Are you making a custom bootable ISO or a general one.

Comment: @markkirby, I am making a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have these also, I definitely have efi, so bit strange, anyway

BOOTX64.efi is [HERE](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/BOOTX64.efi.232971-0.html)

there are loads but they are all mirrors of the same file

efiboot.img is [HERE](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/efiboot.img.360448-0.html) same deal